# Jest with coffeescript jsx?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, reactjs, jestjs

How can I use Jest to test React components written in CoffeeScript + React jsx?

The only CoffeeScript example provided with Jest uses plain CoffeeScript, and doesn't work with CoffeeScript + React JSX (syntax error when it reaches a `<`).

## What I have tried

### first attempt: execSync

```
// preprocessor.js
var execSync = require('exec-sync');

module.exports = {
  process: function (src, path) {
    return execSync('browserify -t coffee-reactify ' + path);
  }
};
```

This works, but takes too much time (a good 12 seconds for a dummy test).

Then I tried:

## second attempt: coffee-react-transform

```
// preprocessor.js
var coffee = require('coffee-script');
var transform = require('coffee-react-transform');

module.exports = {
  process: function(src, path) {
    if (path.match(/\.coffee$/)) {
      return coffee.compile(transform(src), {'bare': true});
    }
    return src;
  }
};
```

This throws a strange error, like:

TypeError: function() {...} has no method 'getPooled'

The only Google result for "has no method 'getPooled'" is [this gist](https://gist.github.com/kristoferjoseph/27c3e09eb1ec3443b5df), that shows exactly the error I get, but offers no other insights.

### third possible attempt

I think I could use [coffee-reactify](https://github.com/jsdf/coffee-reactify"), but it returns a stream, which is asynchronous, while the `process` function in `preprocess.js` is used synchronously, and have found no way, so far, to read a stream synchronously.

What can I do?

Comment: I have not used `coffee-react-transform` but from the docs it seems like it should be used without first compiling the coffeescript? e.g. `return transform(src)` instead of `return coffee.compile(transform(src), {'bare': true});`?

Comment: `transform(src)` returns regular ("de-reactified") coffeescript, which must then be compiled into javascript.

Comment: after some head scratching on my part I _think_ I have gotten this working locally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your second approach was correct, except you did not (I'm guessing here) add react to "unmockedModulePathPatterns" in the `jest` property of package.json. That is typically the result of the `getPooled` error in my experience.

The following works for me:

**package.json**

```
  // ...
  "jest": {
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": ["<rootDir>/node_modules/react"],
    "testFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "coffee"
    ],
    "scriptPreprocessor": "<rootDir>/preprocessor.js"
  }
```

**preprocessor.js**

```
// I found it simpler to use coffee-react,
// since it does the jsx transform and coffeescript compilation 
var coffee = require('coffee-react');

module.exports = {
  process: function(src, path) {
    if (path.match(/\.coffee$/)) {
      return coffee.compile(src, {bare: true});
    }
    return src;
  }
};
```

This whole process is difficult troubleshoot because errors can happen anywhere during the `jsx -> coffee -> js -> jest` pipeline and get silently swallowed. I found it most helpful to troubleshoot this by running the transform in a separate file to make sure the `jsx -> coffee` and `coffee -> js` happened properly, and then run the jest preprocessor.

Comment: Of course you're right! I had tried to tell Jest not to mock `node_modules/react/lib/CallbackQueue.js` (the module that defines `getPooled`), but that didn't work...

Comment: Any idea on how to do this and also support ES6/ES2015 modules?

Answer (score 4):

I have just published a boiler plate unit test for Jest that works with React & CoffeeScript.

https://github.com/Cotidia/jest-react-coffeescript

The preprocessor needs to be as follows:

```
var coffee = require('coffee-script');
var ReactTools = require('react-tools');

module.exports = {
  process: function(src, path) {
    // console.log('src', src);
    if (path.match(/\.coffee$/)) {

        // First we compile the coffeescript files to JSX
        compiled_to_js = coffee.compile(src, {bare: true});

        // Then we compile the JSX to React
        compiled_to_react = ReactTools.transform(compiled_to_js)

      return compiled_to_react;
    }
    return src;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for that!

I've send small changes to your repo

Answer (score 1):

Based on user2534631's template project, I enhanced to use [coffee-react-transform](https://github.com/jsdf/coffee-react-transform) to compile CJSX files.

https://github.com/redice/jest-react-coffeescript

```
var coffee = require('coffee-script');
var transform = require('coffee-react-transform');

module.exports = {
  process: function(src, path) {
    if (coffee.helpers.isCoffee(path)) {
      compiled_cjx = transform(src);
      compiled_to_react = coffee.compile(compiled_cjx, {bare: true});

      return compiled_to_react;
    }

    return src;
  }
};
```

So use CJSX syntax to write React components.

```
render: ->
  <label>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      checked={this.state.isChecked}
      onChange={this.onChange} />
    {if this.state.isChecked then this.props.labelOn else this.props.labelOff}
  </label>
```