# SyntaxError when running a Jest test containing import of a CoffeeScript file

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, jestjs

I am writing a Jest integration test to test my server. Here is my test:

```
import { app, port } from '../server' // the other lines are not so important
...
```

When running `jest` this raises an error:

```
__tests__/graphql.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    <project folder>/node_modules/papercut/lib/papercut.coffee:3
    {FileStore, S3Store, TestStore } = require('./store')
                                     ^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
```

I am requiring `server.js` in my Jest test, this file requires `upload.js` and this file requires node module called `papercut`. The problem is, it's written in CoffeeScript, not pure JS.

At the beginning I had this error: [Jest: cannot find module required inside module to be tested (relative path)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35385920/jest-cannot-find-module-required-inside-module-to-be-tested-relative-path). I added `coffee`  to my `package.json`'s `jest` config like that:

```
"jest": {
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "jsx", "node", "coffee"]
},
```

but now I have the error I've described above.

How can I handle this?

Comment: Maybe take a look at the "Second attempt" part of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27123072/jest-with-coffeescript-jsx) as it shows how to compile the coffee on import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually fixed it by doing 2 things:

- adding a preprocessor for coffee files (like in other question)
- adding `"preprocessorIgnorePatterns": []` to my Jest config. Jest ignores .coffee files inside `node_modules/` if you won't tell it explicitly that you want to compile these files as well.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to setup a [preprocessor](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react.html#custom-preprocessors) for Jest as it can't nativity handle coffee script.

This has already been answered [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27123072/jest-with-coffeescript-jsx) so I won't go into the detail. The reason es6 works "out of the box" is because jest-babel has been provided as es6 is de facto in most React code bases.

Comment: I tried to implement my own preprocessor, now I am getting this error: https://gist.github.com/serge1peshcoff/6823cba9f464ea7e3f920af2d895bb69. Seems like this package uses some ES6 syntax inside CoffeeScript or something like that.

Comment: And also it's strange how it is not compiled by itself, the papercut's `index.js` is requiring `coffee-script` by itself, like that: `require('coffee-script'); module.exports = require('./lib/papercut');`